# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Config'

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

Currently trying to write a program using the neat module. At this point, when I run the program I should be seeing a window pop up with activity going on. Instead I see this message:

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Config'

The bug seems to be in these lines:

```
def run(config_file):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                            neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                            config_file)

    p = neat.Population(config)

    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config-feedforward.txt')
    run(config_path)
```

This snippet is pasted directly from the working source so I am confused as to what the cause could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What specific line does the error occur at?

Comment: File "", line 417, in <module>
    run(config_path)
  File "", line 403, in run
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,

Comment: It seems like `neat.config` is actually a function not a class, module, or object. What's the documentation on that module?

Comment: https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_summaries.html#config Here you go. Any idea why my system would be interpreting in this way when others clearly do not?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another conflicting module or something? Do `dir(neat)` and `dir(neat.config)` to look at what is under each of those modules.

Comment: sample output from dir(neat): '__url__', '__version__', 'config']      sample output from dir(neat.config):etattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']      I notice that config is an attribute of the first but not the second, but am unsure what do make of this. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: This question was asked earlier today but I can't seem to find it. Perhaps it was deleted. Did you `import neat`? There are multiple "neat" projects on pypi.python.org (used by the pip installer). I installed `neat-python` and `neat.config.Config` worked for me. You may have installed the wrong package.

Comment: You could get the package location on disk with `neat.__file__`, go to its directory and see if its the stuff you expect.

Comment: I believe you are correct! following neat.__file__ gives me some sort of WSGI framework I may have accidentally downloaded. Now to work on getting the right neat file imported. Any tips for that? Many thanks! I have done pip install neat-python to no affect seemingly

Comment: You might have to uninstall the previous library before installing the new one.

Comment: All is sorted out (for now). The main issue was I was using IntelliJ to automatically import modules, and it was importing the wrong neat. Much appreciated to both of you